# Is a point a curve?

Tags: differential-geometry

Definition: Let $I$ be an interval of real numbers (i.e. a non-empty connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$). Then a curve $\gamma$ is a continuous mapping $\gamma \colon I \rightarrow X$, where $X$ is a topological space.
It doesn't say anything about the bijective nature of $\gamma$. It just says that its non-simple if its not one-one. So, can all the points in $I$ be mapped to one point in $X$ making it a curve?

Comment: Yup.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Very non-intuitive! Is curvature defined on it? @MikeMiller

Comment: @AnjaniGupta use a curve, make its length goto 0 by limit

Comment: You need $\gamma' \ne 0$ to define the curvature.

Comment: I meant its just a single point, there's no concept of limits and thus derivative there. Then how do we go about finding derivative there and integrating the absolute value of the derivative?

Comment: No, it is not a point. It is a *map*, whose image is a point. The map is $\gamma(t) = v$, where $v$ is some point in the plane. Then because this map is constant, $\gamma'(t) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMiller, but it feels like we take an open set of $R$ and place it in the space at exactly one point like a thread wound and reduced to a point. And usually its the image that we see and talk about when its about continuity, otherwise for surfaces from $R^2$ \rightarrow $R^3$ we would need a 5D graph which we can't even imagine. And if your answer doesn't change can I conclude that all curves are surfaces as well?